# Явные ошибки пользовательского интерфейса в интернационализации/локализации

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В пользовательском интерфейсе многие вещи режут глаза. Вот снимок экрана страницы с вопросом и некоторые предложения по исправлению ошибок:

[image: Ошибки интерфейса]

Что бросилось в глаза:

1. *Метки (Tags)*. Звучит инородно, предложение заменить на *Ярлыки* или транслитеровать как *Тэги*.
2. *Участники (Users)*. Все-таки мы *Пользователи*, а не участники.
3. *Знаки (Badges)*. Правильнее, на мой взгляд, назвать раздел *Награды* или транслитеровать как *Бейджи*.
4. *Тревога*. Это не тревога, это скорее *Поднять флаг* или *Пометить*.
5. *36 раза*, *2 ответов*. Необходимо поработать над интернационализацией/локализацией и учитывать морфологические особенности русского языка: *36 раз*, *2 ответа* и проч.
6. *101 бал*. Бал в русском языке имеет другой смысл: имеется ввиду *балл*.
7. *текущие (active)* / *старые (oldest)* / *голоса (votes)*. Новые пользователи вряд ли смогут понять, что это за переключатели. Правильнее использовать предлог *по*. Например, так: *По активности*, *По дате добавления*, *По рейтингу*.

Кроме этого, на странице пользователя раздел *Все действия* (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176778/skuntsel?tab=activity) не переведен.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше сообщение! У нас тут была длинная дискуссия по поводу перевода. Он пока не идеален, но является по существу результатом [консенсуса участников сайта](http://meta.hashcode.ru/research/3041/). Переводы будут уточняться и исправляться по мере работы сайта.

Comment: По поводу терминов (метки, участники, знаки, тревога и т. п.) вот обсуждение: http://meta.hashcode.ru/research/3048/ На текущий момент такой перевод поддержан большинством. (Хотя сообщество открыто для изменений.)

Comment: - Термин "Метки" был перенесен с ХэшКода "как есть". 4 года мы жили с метками и расставаться нет желания.   
 - "Участники", а не "Пользователи", потому что мы - сообщество, и каждый из нас участник сообщества.

Comment: Ставлю [meta-tag:статус-завершено]. Пункты 5-7 исправлены; 1-4 отклонены. Если вы хотите снова обсудить один из отклоненных пунктов, создайте на Мете новое обсуждение, посвященное только ему.